# How to determine if an open source package from pub.dev would work on flutter 2.0?

Tags: flutter2.0

I tried many packages from pub.dev after upgrading to flutter 2.0, almost none of them really worked. I got different errors during compilation. Is there a way to know what packages would work and which of them would not?

Can I find the compatibility on pub.dev?

Answer (score 0):

I know that every update becomes a headache when talking about packages.

**I use 2 methods to check this and all are working for me:**

- The first one is the "null safety" tag besides the package name or going directly to the package documentation to look for it.
- The second one is funny but I sometimes use it, it the pack version is v xx.0, which means the package is totally moved to its next big release.